# Error: Could not find or load main class on Mac OSX

Tags: java, jar, compiler-errors, executable-jar

I have created a program in eclipse which I have exported to JAR but when I try to run it i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

I don't understand why it cant find it as I have stated where the main class is. my Manifest file looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: gui.GeoMapItMain
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
Class-Path: JMapViewer.jar
Class-Path: colt.jar
Class-Path: metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar
Class-Path: JMapViewer_src.jar
SplashScreen-Image: images/splash.gif
```

I am using java on a Mac with Mountain Lion with the following versions of JDK:

```
javac 1.7.0_13
java version "1.7.0_13"
```

I have now tried this:

```
java -jar GeoMapItJ.jar
```

which gives me an error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openstreetmap/gui/jmapviewer/interfaces/MapMarker
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2694)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.MapMarker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: All depends on the code that you have written. Other than seeing what the results of `java -jar ` are, its a little hard to help out.

Comment: Is there are a `main` method in `gui.GeoMapItMain`?

Comment: is `gui.GeoMapItMain` in one of the JAR files listed in your Class-Path entries? And are those JAR files locatable relative to the path you are running the JAR file from?

Comment: yes there is a main method

Comment: gui.GeoMapItMain is not in the classpath entries as it is a class within the source of my program

Comment: Heck, I didn't even know you could list class path entries separately like that.

Comment: @DaveNewton You can’t!

Comment: @andrewdotn I was being hinty :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax for `Class-Path` in a manifest requires the entries to be space-separated, not to be on separate lines. See the [JAR File Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html).

Having multiple `Class-Path` keys is an error. The `jar` tool will warn you if you pass it the verbose flag:

```
$ jar cvfm foo.jar manifest Foo.class 
Jun 12, 2013 9:53:19 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Jun 12, 2013 9:53:19 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
WARNING: Duplicate name in Manifest: Class-Path.
Ensure that the manifest does not have duplicate entries, and
that blank lines separate individual sections in both your
manifest and in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF entry in the jar file.
Jun 12, 2013 9:53:19 PM java.util.jar.Attributes read
...
```

The extra `Class-Path` entries are being ignored, which causes the exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openstreetmap.gui.jmapviewer.interfaces.MapMarker
```

because the class is not specified in the `Class-Path` entry that is processed.